# Pass output of a target as a value

Tags: svn, ant, build.xml, manifest.mf

Is it possible to pass the output of an ant target as the value of something else? Such as:

```
<target name="svnrevision">
        <exec executable="svnversion" outputproperty="svnversion" />
    </target>

<target name="jar">
        ...
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="irrelevant" value="${svnversion}"/>
            </manifest> 
    </target>
```

Where `${svnversion}` would be something like 12345.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a dependency between he targets

```
<target name="jar" depends="svnversion">
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my own problem by having the

`<exec executable="svnversion" outputproperty="svnversion" />`

line be within the `jar` target itself. Ant didn't seem to be able to figure out what I was trying to do when it was  in a separate target.